# How to use map to dig out data from api in angular 5

Tags: angular

Hello everyone I need your help please, I am using angular 5 and i'm new to angular I am unable to get data out of what my api service is returning

according to my html code I did this

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let cat of categories">
<span class="badge">{{cat.id}}</span> {{cat.name}}
 </li>
</ul>
```

The li tag repeat the exact number of data in my Db but I cant see the data all I see is repitition of the li tag

Here is my code

The same structure with my server code

```
export class Category
   {
    id: number;
    name: string;
   }
```

I called the server like this

```
product.service code:

       getCategories (): Observable<Category[]> 
         {
       return this.http.get<Category[]>
        ('http://localhost:56757/api/product/categories')
        .pipe(
         tap(categories` => this.log(`fetched categories`)),
         catchError(this.handleError('getCategories', []))
          );
         }
```

Category.component.ts code

```
       products:Product[];


          constructor(private productService: ProductService,
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private location: Location) { }
           ngOnInit() {
           getCategories(): void {
           this.productService.getCategories()
           .subscribe(products => this.products = products);
           }
```

HTML :

```
        <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let cat of categories">
          <span class="badge">{{cat.id}}</span> {{cat.name}}
         </li>
         </ul>
```

According to Angular Documentation that goes like this, 
"Other APIs may bury the data that you want within an object. 
You might have to dig that data out by processing the Observable result with the RxJS map operator."

Please can someone help me with how to use map to dig the data out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does a Category object look like when it comes back from the DB? Can you print it to the console? If you try and access the name and id properties on it does it throw an error?

Comment: I don't get errors when I try to access the properties of Category, I tried to print to the console I cant find any object in the console

Comment: I need someone to help me on this I have been battling with it for the past 3 weeks

Comment: I can’t help you without seeing the server side code responding to the request

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brendan here is the asp.net server side codes

Model :

```
           public class Category
            {        
           public int Id { get; set; }

           public string Name { get; set; }    
             }



         [HttpGet]
         [Route("categories")]
         public async Task<List<Category>> GetCategory() => await 
         db.Categories.ToListAsync();
```